# Submit multiple forms created by foreach loop with one button

Tags: html, laravel, forms, foreach

In my blade template, I use a foreach to create one form per iteration. Currently, each form has a submit button, but I want to use one submit button to submit all the form, because now I cannot submit all forms at the same time. How can I fix this?

```
@if(count($task_criterias) > 0)
    @foreach($task_criterias as $task_criteria)
        <td class="card">
            <div>Description:{{$task_criteria->criteriadescription}}</div>
            <div>Maximum Mark:{{$task_criteria->maximummark}}</div>

            {!! Form::open([
                'action' => 'CriteriaMarksController@store',
                'method' => 'POST',
                'name' => "form"
            ]) !!}

            <div class="form-group" hidden >
                {{ Form::label('criteria_id', 'criteria_id') }}
                {{ Form::text('criteria_id', $task_criteria->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{ Form::label('selfmark','Mark ') }}
                {{ Form::number('selfmark', '',['placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) }}
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    @endforeach

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info " value="Submit" onclick="submitForms()" />

    <script>
        submitForms = function() {
            $("form").each(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:'/criteria_marks/post',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(r){
                        //...
                    }
                });
             });
         }
     </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one post submit per request. One of the easiest solution is to perfom multiple requests using ajax:

```
<script>
submitForms = function() {
  $("form").each(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:'* route to CriteriaMarksController@store *',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(r){
                //...
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Or you can make one big form:

```
{!! Form::open([
            'action' => 'CriteriaMarksController@store',
            'method' => 'POST',
            'name' => "form"
     ]) !!}
@foreach($task_criterias as $key => $task_criteria)
    <td class="card">
      <div>Description:{{$task_criteria->criteriadescription}}</div>
      <div>Maximum Mark:{{$task_criteria->maximummark}}</div>

     <div>
       {{ Form::label('selfmark','Mark ') }}
       {{ Form::number('selfmark['.$task_criteria->id.']', '',
         ['placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) }}
     </div>

   </td>
 @endforeach 
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info " value="Submit"  /> 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This will form associative array selfmark in post with id => value pairs

Comment: The ajax function works awesome. but the HTML form one did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with the `Form` facade.

What you have now is:

```
<input name="criteria_id" value="{{ $task_criteria->id }}" />
<input name="selfmark" value="{{ $task_criteria->id }}" />
```

But what you need to have is:

```
<input name="criteria_id[]" value="{{ $task_criteria->id }}" />
<input name="selfmark[]" />
```

Note the `[]` in the input names.